# Compare TimeSpan in certain format

Tags: c#

I just need a hand with trying to compare `TimeSpan` values. I've looked at MSDN, however the example there doesn't help me much unfortunately.

I get my `TimeSpans` from two strings formatted as `mm:ss.ffff`. I'd like to be able to compare them. The code I have so far:

```
TimeSpan elapsed;
TimeSpan maxExpected;
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(MaximumValue))
{
    maxExpected = TimeSpan.ParseExact(MaximumValue, "G", null);
    elapsed = TimeSpan.ParseExact(ElapsedTime, "G", null);
    return elapsed < maxExpected;
}

return false;
```

It throws an exception of: `System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid TimeSpan.`

So I'm not sure what I use for format parameter that `ParseExact` expects?

Comment: Have you seen this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.op_lessthanorequal(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Do you have your windows locale settings using a [.] (dot) or a [,]  (comma) as decimal separator?

Comment: Where do I find those? MSDN was the one suggesting I use mm:ss.ffff as format to display the milliseconds correctly. I'd still want the dot to be used as decimal separator in other cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).  Try this, using `DateTime` instead of `TimeSpan`:

```
maxExpected = DateTime.ParseExact(MaximumValue, "mm.ss.ffff", null);
elapsed = DateTime.ParseExact(ElapsedTime, "mm.ss.ffff", null);
return elapsed < maxExpected;
```

Comment: I'm still getting an Incorrent format exception even though I pass in the value 00:02.0000 - the format specified :(

Comment: Cool. Thank you, that works. Though I still don't know why TimeSpan could not parse the value into specified format still?